# What are the rules regarding one antecedent followed by many relative pronouns?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Are any of these correct? What rules are at play here?

- I saw the car which has five wheels and which we passed by earlier.
- I saw the car which has five wheels which we passed by earlier.
- I saw the car which has five wheels that we passed by earlier.

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: What do you mean by "rules"?

Comment: @BillJ Well for starters I'd like to know if all of the sentences are grammatical correct. By rules I mean surely one cannot keep concatenating relative clauses on the same antecedent forever, and under what circumstances are conjunctions between the relative clauses required. For example `I saw the car which is red which crashed into the fence` feels (at least to me) like an _and_ is required between the two relative clauses. Also, is there a name for these types of relative clauses where one antecedent is followed by more than one relativizer?

Comment: I see no way of answering that has a concise and unequivocal answer. As @marcellothearcane points out, *"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."*  As it stands, your question would require a lot of work to answer. For some questions, the extra effort is justified but not this one in my opinion.  I suggest you edit the question and ask for it to be reopened, or write a new one that is more focused. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

We do not have rules as such but there are conventions. Here is what native speakers would say.

I saw the car with five wheels that we passed by earlier.

I saw the five-wheeled car that we passed by earlier.

There's something that's hilarious and also quite rude.

There's something hilarious and also quite rude.

Comment: I know how native speakers would phrase the sentences. Those are artificial constructions; see my comment above.

Comment: Okay, but the title of the SE is *English Language and Usage*, it isn't *English Language and  Artificial Constructions*.  It would help perhaps if you explained your motivation for asking.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Sure I made those sentences up to ask about the rules when you have one antecedent followed by many relative pronouns, but they are still sentences that are likely to be said even by native speakers. So if you'd could address the questions I made in the aforementioned comment that'd be appreciated.

Comment: I see no way of answering that has a concise and unequivocal answer. As @marcellothearcane points out, *"This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."*  As it stands, your question would require a lot of work to answer. For some questions, the extra effort is justified but not this one in my opinion.  I suggest you edit the question and ask for it to be reopened, or write a new one that is more focused. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've removed the second sentence so what's left is essentially one sentence with small variations, variations which may very well have to do with the very rules I'm enquiring about. RE your being unable to give a concise and unequivocal answer, couldn't your answer just be in sections each dealing with just one of the sentence? I don't see any point making 3 questions each with small variations of the same sentence when they are all about the same specific phenomenon. Or maybe someone can enlighten me as to how these sentences are wildly different?

Comment: It's complicated because US English makes a big distinction between "that" and "which". This distinction is not always  followed in British English.   If we focus on British English then I can't find a specific error of grammar in any of them. If you want a preference then I find that impossible to answer because I just wouldn't say any of those sentences. My opinion is  they are equally grammatically correct but equally non-idiomatic. That's the best I can do.