# Demonstrative "which"?

Tags: british-english, demonstratives

I was watching a British panel show from the early 2000s, and at the end of each episode, a buzzer would indicate that the time was up.
What was strange was the way in which the host would react to the buzzer; it would almost always go something like this:

> "And that means one point for Team A."
>
> *alarm goes off*
>
> "Which irritating sound means time is up."

That is, the host seemed to use "which" as a synonym for "that," and I couldn't find anything online to indicate that this was a standard usage, but I also didn't know whether it was just specific to British English.

Is this a valid use of the word "which"?

Comment: Yeah, you run across that occasionally; the speaker is treating the noise in the immediate context as if it were speech, which qualifies it as a relative clause antecedent. Just barely. Similar situation: "That's 13 to 10, which result is final".

Comment: That use of which is very 19th century.

Comment: @JohnLawler So it's kind of like the noise was the first half of the sentence?

Comment: @wintergreen_plaza Yes. The speaker is putting themselves in the position of having made the noise.

Comment: It's common for TV personalities' catchphrases to not be entirely grammatical, or at least elliptical: "Nice to see you, to see you nice." The same is true of advertising slogans, jokes, and many other usages of language. You could compare a sentence like "The monuments spoken of in the second Part of the following Poem, which monuments do now exist as I have there described them." (Wordsworth) But it's fair to say it's not a common use of "which", and not one to use in your daily speech (unless you're on TV).

Answer (score 1):

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/which) certainly includes this usage, specifying an American flavour rather than a British one:

> **which** [in American English]
>
> ...
>
> [adjective]
>
> ...
>
> 8. being the one just mentioned
>
> - *he is very old, which fact is important*

I include this with reservations, as

(1) The usage is certainly not unknown in the UK

(2) There needs to be at least a [formal] caveat, and there is a legalese flavour

(3) This usage is certainly not adjectival. It is that of a determiner / determinative (sunclass demonstrative, as OP says)

OP's example is a clever extension, there having been no prior mention of course, but the usage is justified as the alarm has announced itself.

Answer (score 0):

One purpose for using ***which*** here is to avoid ambiguity by pointing out that the speaker's intent is to refer to the sound of the alarm as the antecedent of the second sentence and not to ***team A***, nor the whole first sentence, nor anything else.

This reminds of the archaic repetition of antecedents of relatives in legal English, and using this over-formal language in a TV show can cause a comic effect. You will find the answer to the EL&U question *[Why does legal English sometimes repeat the antecedent noun after "which"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/551986/what-are-the-rules-regarding-one-antecedent-followed-by-many-relative-pronouns)* quite informative.

And yes,

> Which irritating sound means time is up.

is a relative clause with the sound of the alarm as a referent. Expressed in a less lively way, the sentence would be:

> The irritating sound of the alarm means time is up.

Answer (score -1):

In context, "which" is a determiner. The sentence is valid.

*"Which coat belongs to which child?" / "Tell me which road leads to Rome."* / 1993   New Scientist 11 Dec. 19/1   *This tells other worker bees how far to fly and in which direction.*